# Unable to scroll the react-virtualized List using mouse scroll down when using with react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, react-virtualized

I am unable to scroll down the list in react-select with mouse scroll down.

https://codesandbox.io/s/bvaughnreact-window-integration-with-react-select-forked-15ccs?file=/index.js